# Hbase ClassNotFoundException

Tags: hbase, classnotfoundexception

I want to run a map reduce example:

```
package my.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
 
import org.apache.commons.cli.BasicParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLineParser;
import org.apache.commons.cli.HelpFormatter;
import org.apache.commons.cli.Options;
import org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.MultiTableOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

     
    
     
    /**
     * This class demonstrates the use of the MultiTableOutputFormat class.
     * Using this class we can write the output of a Hadoop map reduce program
     * into different HBase table.
     *
     * @version 1.0 19 Jul 2011
     * @author  Wildnove
     */
    public class TestMultiTable extends Configured implements Tool {
     
        private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(TestMultiTable.class);
        private static final String CMDLINE = "com.wildnove.tutorial.TestMultiTable <inputFile> [-n name] [-s]";
     
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            int res = ToolRunner.run(new TestMultiTable(), args);
            System.exit(res);
        }
     
        @Override
        public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
            HelpFormatter help = new HelpFormatter();
            Options options = new Options();
            options.addOption("h", "help", false, "print program usage");
            options.addOption("n", "name", true, "sets job name");
            CommandLineParser parser = new BasicParser();
            CommandLine cline;
            try {
                cline = parser.parse(options, args);
                args = cline.getArgs();
                if (args.length < 1) {
                    help.printHelp(CMDLINE, options);
                    return -1;
                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                e.printStackTrace();
                help.printHelp(CMDLINE, options);
                return -1;
            }
     
            String name = null;
            try {
                if (cline.hasOption('n'))
                    name = cline.getOptionValue('n');
                else
                    name = "wildnove.com - Tutorial MultiTableOutputFormat ";
                Configuration conf = getConf();
                FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
                Path inputFile = new Path(fs.makeQualified(new Path(args[0])).toUri().getPath());
                if (!getMultiTableOutputJob(name, inputFile).waitForCompletion(true))
                    return -1;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                e.printStackTrace();
                help.printHelp(CMDLINE, options);
                return -1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
     
        /**
         * Here we configure our job to use MultiTableOutputFormat class as map reduce output.
         * Note that we use 1 reduce only for debugging purpose, but you can use more than 1 reduce.
         */
        private Job getMultiTableOutputJob(String name, Path inputFile) throws IOException {
            if (LOG.isInfoEnabled()) {
                LOG.info(name + " starting...");
                LOG.info("computing file: " + inputFile);
            }
            Job job = new Job(getConf(), name);
            job.setJarByClass(TestMultiTable.class);
            job.setMapperClass(Mapper.class);
            job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, inputFile);
            job.setOutputFormatClass(MultiTableOutputFormat.class);
            job.setNumReduceTasks(1);
            job.setReducerClass(Reducer.class);
     
            return job;
        }
     
        private static class Mapper extends org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
     
            private Text outKey = new Text();
            private Text outValue = new Text();
     
            /**
             * The map method splits the csv file according to this structure
             * brand,model,size (e.g. Cadillac,Seville,Midsize) and output all data using
             * brand as key and the couple model,size as value.
             */
            @Override
            public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
                String[] valueSplitted = value.toString().split(",");
                if (valueSplitted.length == 3) {
                    String brand = valueSplitted[0];
                    String model = valueSplitted[1];
                    String size = valueSplitted[2];
     
                    outKey.set(brand);
                    outValue.set(model + "," + size);
                    context.write(outKey, outValue);
                }
            }
        }
     
        private static class Reducer extends org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer<Text, Text, ImmutableBytesWritable, Writable> {
     
            /**
             * The reduce method fill the TestCars table with all csv data,
             * compute some counters and save those counters into the TestBrandsSizes table.
             * So we use two different HBase table as output for the reduce method.
             */
            @Override
            protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
                Map<String, Integer> statsSizeCounters = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                String brand = key.toString();
                // We are receiving all models,size grouped by brand.
                for (Text value : values) {
                    String[] valueSplitted = value.toString().split(",");
                    if (valueSplitted.length == 2) {
                        String model = valueSplitted[0];
                        String size = valueSplitted[1];
     
                        // Fill the TestCars table
                        ImmutableBytesWritable putTable = new ImmutableBytesWritable(Bytes.toBytes("TestCars"));
                        byte[] putKey = Bytes.toBytes(brand + "," + model);
                        byte[] putFamily = Bytes.toBytes("Car");
                        Put put = new Put(putKey);
                        // qualifier brand
                        byte[] putQualifier = Bytes.toBytes("brand");
                        byte[] putValue = Bytes.toBytes(brand);
                        put.add(putFamily, putQualifier, putValue);
                        // qualifier model
                        putQualifier = Bytes.toBytes("model");
                        putValue = Bytes.toBytes(model);
                        put.add(putFamily, putQualifier, putValue);
                        // qualifier size
                        putQualifier = Bytes.toBytes("size");
                        putValue = Bytes.toBytes(size);
                        put.add(putFamily, putQualifier, putValue);
                        context.write(putTable, put);
     
                        // Compute some counters: number of different sizes for a brand
                        if (!statsSizeCounters.containsKey(size))
                            statsSizeCounters.put(size, 1);
                        else
                            statsSizeCounters.put(size, statsSizeCounters.get(size) + 1);
                    }
                }
     
                for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : statsSizeCounters.entrySet()) {
                    // Fill the TestBrandsSizes table
                    ImmutableBytesWritable putTable = new ImmutableBytesWritable(Bytes.toBytes("TestBrandsSizes"));
                    byte[] putKey = Bytes.toBytes(brand);
                    byte[] putFamily = Bytes.toBytes("BrandSizes");
                    Put put = new Put(putKey);
                    // We can use as qualifier the sizes
                    byte[] putQualifier = Bytes.toBytes(entry.getKey());
                    byte[] putValue = Bytes.toBytes(entry.getValue());
                    put.add(putFamily, putQualifier, putValue);
                    context.write(putTable, put);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

build to jar `mt.jar` with eclipse options :jar file

run the mapreduce:

```
[zhouhh@Hadoop48 ~]$ HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`${HBASE_HOME}/bin/hbase classpath`:`${HADOOP_HOME}/bin/hadoop classpath`  ${HADOOP_HOME}/bin/hadoop jar  mt.jar cars.csv 12/06/11 20:14:33 INFO test.TestMultiTable: wildnove.com - Tutorial MultiTableOutputFormat  starting... 12/06/11 20:14:33 INFO test.TestMultiTable: computing file: /user/zhouhh/cars.csv 12/06/11 20:14:34 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1 12/06/11 20:14:34 INFO util.NativeCodeLoader: Loaded the native-hadoop library 12/06/11 20:14:34 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded 12/06/11 20:14:35 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201206111811_0012 12/06/11 20:14:36 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0% 12/06/11 20:14:42 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201206111811_0012_m_000002_0, Status : FAILED java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.MultiTableOutputFormat
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:867)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobContext.getOutputFormatClass(JobContext.java:235)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task.initialize(Task.java:513)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:353)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.MultiTableOutputFormat
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:820)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:865)
```

`cars.csv`:

```
[zhouhh@Hadoop48 ~]$ cat cars.csv Acura,Integra,Small Acura,Legend,Midsize Audi,90,Compact Audi,100,Midsize BMW,535i,Midsize Buick,Century,Midsize Buick,LeSabre,Large Buick,Roadmaster,Large Buick,Riviera,Midsize Cadillac,DeVille,Large Cadillac,Seville,Midsize
```

`MultiTableOutputFormat.class` is in `Hbase.0.94.jar`

```
[zhouhh@Hadoop48 ~]$ echo $HADOOP_CLASSPATH |tr ':' '\n' | grep hbase /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/conf /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0 /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/hbase-0.94.0.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/hbase-0.94.0-tests.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/activation-1.1.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/asm-3.1.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/avro-1.5.3.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/avro-ipc-1.5.3.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/commons-math-2.1.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/commons-net-1.4.1.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/core-3.1.1.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/guava-r09.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/hadoop-core-1.0.2.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/high-scale-lib-1.1.1.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/httpclient-4.1.2.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/httpcore-4.1.3.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.5.5.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.5.5.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.5.5.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jackson-xc-1.5.5.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jamon-runtime-2.3.1.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jaxb-api-2.1.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jersey-core-1.4.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jersey-json-1.4.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jersey-server-1.4.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jettison-1.1.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.5.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jsp-api-2.1-6.1.14.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/libthrift-0.8.0.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/netty-3.2.4.Final.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/snappy-java-1.0.3.2.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/velocity-1.7.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/zookeeper-3.4.3.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/conf /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0 /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/hbase-0.94.0.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/hbase-0.94.0-tests.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/activation-1.1.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/asm-3.1.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/avro-1.5.3.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/avro-ipc-1.5.3.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/commons-io-2.1.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/commons-math-2.1.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/commons-net-1.4.1.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/core-3.1.1.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/guava-r09.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/hadoop-core-1.0.2.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/high-scale-lib-1.1.1.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/httpclient-4.1.2.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/httpcore-4.1.3.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.5.5.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.5.5.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.5.5.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jackson-xc-1.5.5.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jamon-runtime-2.3.1.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jaxb-api-2.1.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jaxb-impl-2.1.12.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jersey-core-1.4.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jersey-json-1.4.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jersey-server-1.4.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jettison-1.1.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jruby-complete-1.6.5.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/jsp-api-2.1-6.1.14.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/libthrift-0.8.0.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/netty-3.2.4.Final.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/snappy-java-1.0.3.2.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/stax-api-1.0.1.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/velocity-1.7.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar /home/zhouhh/hbase-0.94.0/lib/zookeeper-3.4.3.jar
```

I have tried many methods, but the same error still there.

Comment: Please format the outputs. It is unreadable this way. Use the `{}` to make the outputs print as code. It looks better.

Answer (score 4):

You have two easy options:

1) Build a fat jar, where your `mt.jar` file includes the `hbase-0.94.0.jar`  (can be done with `mvn package -Dfatjar` )

2) Use the `GenericOptionsParser` (I think you are trying to by implementing `Tool`) and then specify the -libjars parameter on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with the same. My this post has it working - https://my-bigdata-blog.blogspot.in/2017/08/Hbase-Programming-Java-Netbeans-Maven.html
You need below line in code along with setting Hadoop_classpath.
TableMapReduceUtil.addDependencyJars(job);

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following script to add job's dependencies in lib folder and hbase's dependencies to job's classpath:

```
cp=$(find `pwd` -name '*.jar' | tr '\n', ',')
cp=$cp$(hbase mapredcp 2>&1 | tail -1 | tr ':' ',')
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`echo ${cp} | sed s/,/:/g`
hadoop jar `pwd`/bin/mr.jar \
--libjars ${cp} \
$@
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 `hadoop classpath`
```

and

```
`hbase classpath`
```

will give cluster classpath export this to HADOOP_CLASSPATH. (is standard way to utilize cluster's local environment).

- Capture above in a variable and we need to format using Linux commands.
  add it to `-libjars` option of the mapreduce if was not finding the jar which you are looking for.