# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, hbase, classnotfoundexception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat
```

I cannot put the `hbase jar` files to `Hadoop` lib directory, because I am not allowed to change such `configurations` on the given cluster.

What other alternatives can you offer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my question.

I fixed this using `libjars` option with Hadoop.

```
export libpath=/path to hbase jar
hadoop jar myjarname.jar <classpath> arguments -libjar ${libpath}
```

Comment: Can you please specify which jar to add. I am using cloudera 5(cdh5.5).

Answer (score 0):

Jar containing `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat` is missing
 [download jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhbase0901jar.htm) and set your `classpath`

Comment: No. it's not missing.

Comment: chechout this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980072/hbase-classnotfoundexception

Comment: it was solved today by using -libjars, thanks anyways!