# error in running hbase java program

Tags: maven, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, apache-zookeeper

this is my java hbase createtable program below:-

```
 public class createtable 
 {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 

  {   
       Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();    
       conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "sandbox.hortonworks.com");
       conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
       conf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-unsecure");
       HBaseAdmin admin = new HBaseAdmin(conf);
       HTableDescriptor tableDescriptor = new HTableDescriptor(TableName.valueOf("people"));
       tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("personal"));
       tableDescriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("contactinfo"));
       admin.createTable(tableDescriptor);
       Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("doe-john-m-12345");     
   }
```

after creating jar (table-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar) of the program when  i am running the command 
 hadoop jar table-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar table.createtable

i am getting

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/apachehadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration at 
    table.createtable.main(createtable.java:17)
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.jav     a:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148)                           Causedby:
     java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBase
     Configuration     
     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more

 how do i resolve this error ??
```

Comment: I just answered it in another question over [here][1] - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980072/hbase-classnotfoundexception/45676822#45676822

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not able to see **hbase.jar** . Try adding this piece in your **pom.xml**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
    <version>0.90.2</version>
</dependency>
```

And then run it .

Comment: do i have to add hbase version( 0.90.2 ),,its still showing same error after adding hbase jar

Comment: add version please

Comment: my hbase version is 1.2.6 after adding the dependency -> Missing artifact org.apache.hbase:hbase:jar:1.2.6 in pom.xml

Comment: add this to your pom.xml <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-common -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>hbase-common</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.6</version>
</dependency>

Comment: already added these jars.. hbase-client >> hbase-common >> hadoop-common >> hadoop-common >> hadoop-client >>hbase 1.2.6

Comment: Missing artifact org.apache.hbase:hbase:jar:1.2.6

Comment: rebuild your project please

Comment: i am rebuilding project again but when i am adding hbase jar 1.2.6 it is giving me error  Missing artifact org.apache.hbase:hbase:jar:1.2.6 ..what can i do sir ??

Comment: can you post your pom.xml

Comment: its too long to fit here..can i get your contact id sir..or where i can send u ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45707166/hadoop-2-8-0-and-hbase-1-2-6-version-compatibility --- is this the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Please read this blog: https://my-bigdata-blog.blogspot.com/2017/08/hbase-programming-on-map-reduce-with.html

Two points to make it work

1) You code should have TableMapReduceUtil.addDependencyJars(job);

2) On command line - before you execute the command do this:

export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=your-jar-path

export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:`hbase classpath`

This adds hbase libraries for execution. The one you add in maven/netbeans are for compilation.

Comment: Please explain what the step 2 does and why it is needed

Comment: Step 2 adds hbase librarys for execution.  The one you add in maven/netbeans are for compilation. That hbase classpath should be in quotes for execution.  Not able to add them in here..

Comment: okay..i think problem is in HADOOP_CLASSPATH in hadoop env.sh..what i have to set in  export HADOOP_CLASSPATH ??

Answer (score 0):

i solved this issue as there is issue in making fat jar and the in new hbase version jars are deprecated with many dependency..so i also added hbase-client-1.2.6-jar and hbase-common-1.2.6-jar to eclipse externally and then building fat jar ...this solved my issue .